# How to use IsNullOrEmpty in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, isnullorempty

Why doesn't the following compile in VB.NET?

```
Dim strTest As String
If (strTest.IsNullOrEmpty) Then
   MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY")
End if
```

Comment: The compiler says: `Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Shared Function IsNullOrEmpty(value As String) As Boolean'.`, so you could guess it's because you didn't specify an argument for the parameter `value` of that method. What I want to say is that (most of the time) the compiler will tell you what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

IsNullOrEmpty is 'shared' so you should use it that way:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTest) Then
```

Answer (score 10):

You can actually just compare to an empty string:

```
If strTest = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY")
End If
```

Comment: What if `strTest` is `nothing`? `IsNullOrEmpty` explicitly contains a check whether `strTest` is `nothing`. Your statement does not check this.

Comment: Actually it does, string comparison against an empty string will return true for Nothing too in VB. Try it out if you don't believe me. Or maybe this convinces you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633166/nothing-string-empty-why-are-these-equal

Comment: +1 @ThorstenDittmar, Rolf is right on this one. VB.Net treats `Nothing` as identical `""` when doing string comparisons (and in other places too).

Comment: @MarkJ: Sorry, didn't know that. Tried to undo my downvote, but SO won't let me unless the answer is edited...?

Answer (score 9):

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) is a shared (or static, in C#) method.

```
Dim strTest As String
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTest)) Then
   MessageBox.Show("NULL OR EMPTY")
End if
```

Comment: When I do that it says that a NullPointerException could be raised at runtime.

Comment: @CJ7 It's because you use `strTest` without setting a value (which *could* be a mistake), so it is always `Nothing`. You can get around it by using `Dim strTest As String = Nothing` e.g. to explicitly set it to `Nothing`.

Comment: @Mr.Steak: that seems a bit strange because if I don't set it to anything it will be `Nothing` anyway. Why should I have to explicitly set it to `Nothing` - doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @CJ7 Yes, it will be `Nothing` anyway, but since you didn't explicitly  tell the compiler so, it just warns you that it *could* be a bug in your code (hence it's just a warning, not an error). Note that you can disable those warnings, but I would not recommend doing so.