# What is the difference between vbNullString, String.Empty and ""?

Tags: vb.net, string-comparison

All of these

- `txtUsername.Text <> vbNullString`
- `txtUsername.Text <> String.Empty`
- `txtUsername.Text <> ""`

seem to return the same result. So, what's the difference between `vbNullString`, `String.Empty` and `""`?

Comment: How about `IsNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: Arman means `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

vbNullString is a constant, more likely out of VB6, `String.Empty` and `""` are the same, some say that there is a performance difference, but that is not true, it is your choice what you use.

To check whether a string is empty you can use `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)`. The advantage is that it will also check for *null*, because string is a class and because of this a reference type.

Answer (score 26):

### What's the difference?

- `String.Empty` and `""` both represent a string of length zero.
- Contrary to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnullstring(v=vs.110).aspx), which claims that `vbNullString` "*[r]epresents a zero-length string*", `vbNullString` is actually `Nothing` (`null` in C#, see [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.cs,d63b2a5a29ea6c43)).

(Note that this only applies to VB.NET! The situation is different in VBA, see below for details.)

### So how do I check if a string is null/Nothing or empty?

Contrary to what the other answer says, you do not need to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check for `Nothing` or an empty string, since the `=` operator in Visual Basic treats Nothing and an empty string as equivalent. Thus, the idiomatic way to check for "null or empty string" in VB.NET is to simply use `= ""`:

```
Dim s As String = Nothing
If s = "" Then Console.WriteLine("YES")     ' Prints YES
```

Thus, `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`, `s <> ""`, `s <> String.Empty` and `s <> vbNullString` are all equivalent. I prefer the concise `s <> ""`, but it's mainly a question of preference and style.

### Does that mean that I can use an empty string and Nothing interchangeably?

In general: no. This equivalence of an empty string and Nothing is only true for VB.NET's built-in `=` and `<>` operators as well as most of the methods in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace (`Len(...)`, `Trim(...)`, ...). Once you go into pure .NET territory (for example, by using methods from the rest of the Base Class Library), Nothing and the empty string are treated differently:

```
Dim sNothing As String = Nothing
Dim sEmpty As String = ""

Console.WriteLine(sEmpty = sNothing)                ' True
Console.WriteLine(sEmpty.Equals(sNothing))          ' False
Console.WriteLine(String.Equals(sEmpty, sNothing))  ' False

Console.WriteLine(Len(sEmpty))                      ' 0
Console.WriteLine(Len(sNothing))                    ' 0
Console.WriteLine(sEmpty.Length)                    ' 0
Console.WriteLine(sNothing.Length)                  ' throws a NullReferenceException
```

### Why is `vbNullString` defined as `Nothing` instead of `""`?

Backwards compatibility. In VBA (and "VB Classic"), `vbNullString` could be used to get a "null string reference"¹. Within VBA, `vbNullString` was treated like the empty string `""`, but when interacting with non-VB-code, [`vbNullString` was mapped to the NULL pointer and `""` was mapped to an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435320/87698).

When using PInvoke in VB.NET, `Nothing` is mapped to the NULL pointer and `""` is mapped to an empty string, so it makes sense to have the legacy constant `vbNullString` equal `Nothing` in VB.NET.

---

¹ which is completely different from VBA's `Null` and `Empty`, which are special `Variant` subtypes, and VBA's `Nothing`, which, in VBA, only applies to objects and not to strings.

Comment: I had not caught that `vbNullString` was equal to `Nothing`. Thanks for that! The documentation is quite contradictory because it actually also indicates this is a constant defined to `Nothing`: `public const string vbNullString = null;`

Answer (score 1):

If are going to insert values to MS-SQL database and if column doesn't allows null(Not null) then strValue=vbNullString will generate exception but strValue="" will insert blank spaces.

Comment: That is nothing more than a very specific case illustrating a consequence of the fact that `vbNullString = Nothing`, as already covered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34069187/1188513)...