# VBA array: "Testarray(10)" – What are the initial values of this *without* assigning *any* value to *any* cell?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, initialization

When I am programming in VBA, I want to initialise an array as

```
Dim Testarray(10) As String
```

Now: *What* are the initial values of this array without further ado?

Or asked in another way: I want to use this `Testarray` in order to find out certain values. These certain values are then changed to `"Missing Line"` or whatsoever. By that, I am able to check all the array values later on in order to find the number of my missing values by going through the respective array via, e.g., a `for`-loop or something like that.

*(**Bonus question:** Right now, I am learning how to write VBA code. Does an array always have to have a name beginning with a **capital** letter? Or is it also allowed to begin it with a small letter?)*

Comment: When declaring `Dim Testarray(10) As String` , all 11 elements of Testarray are `""`. Regarding the Bonus, the name doesn’t have to start with Capital letters, even though I personally prefer all my variables to start with capital letters (for debug purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the keyword vbNullString to check for empty or uninitialized elements of your newly created string array.

```
Dim Testarray(10) As String
Testarray(5) = "Test"
For i = 0 To UBound(Testarray)
    If Testarray(i) = vbNullString Then
        ' skip
    Else
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Testarray(i)
    End If

Next
```

Will print "Test" in row 6 column 1 (A), and skip all uninitialized elements. As others have mentioned, in VBA testing for a blank string ("") will produce the same results in the about code snippet. This does not translate to the rest of the .NET framework however, where strings are a little more complex. For that you would use the String.IsNullOrEmpty function.

Answer (score 2):

The default value of a `String` is `vbNullString`.

This constant evaluates to `""` in comparisons, and the difference between `""` and `vbNullString` [seems to be very small and pertaining mostly to memory economics on a tiny scale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796912/4604845).

Take this example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Testarray(10) As String

    Debug.Print Testarray(1) = ""
    Debug.Print Testarray(1) = vbNullString
End Sub
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for for a string is the empty string `""`.

As for the bonus question, short answer - no it doesn't matter. Long answer - vba itself is case insensitive, ie you can define names in whatever case you want and then refer to them in the same or a different case. However, most development environments (including the one in excel) will automatically change all further references to a name to the case in which you defined it.