# Excel VBA bug/anomaly - ActiveWorkbook.Save changes Workbook_BeforeSave function

Tags: vba, excel

In my code I use a `Workbook_BeforeSave` function that does some text formatting.

When I hit the Save button, it runs and formats the size and font type of some cells.
Here is part of my code that does the job:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

For Each c In rng
    If ispcname(c.Value) = True Or isip(c.Value) = True Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="": c.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter: c = StrConv(c, vbProperCase): c.Font.Name = "Arial": c.Font.Size = "10"
    If Right(c, 1) = "$" Then 
        y = c.Column: x = c.Row

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If LCase(Cells(i, y).Value) = "backup" Then
                If  Right(c, 1) = "$" Then Cells(x, y) = Cells(x, y - 2) & "$": ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="": c.Font.Name = "Calibri": c.Font.Size = "10": c.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter: c.Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I have recently implemented a code that will save the Workbook if it is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Then something went wrong that I can't explain. When `ActiveWorkbook.Save` runs, the cells that should change into `Calibri`, change into `Arial` instead, size remains unmodified, color is working normally. However when I manually hit the save button it works as it should. (changes the cells back to `Calibri`)

There is no other code interfering because when I commented out the part that changes the font type to `Calibri`, the `ActiveWorkbook.Save` also stopped changing it into `Arial` as well.

My questions are:

- Why is this happening? Is this a bug?
- Is there any workaround?

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Could the value of `ispcname(c.Value) = True Or isip(c.Value) = True` be affecting it?  Also, maybe use `ThisWorkbook.Save` or even `ActiveSheet.Parent.Save` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. I'd also split the `If isbackup = True And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then Cells(x, y) = Cells(x, y....` line into seperate rows within an `IF...END IF` block rather than `:` separated commands (easier to read).

Comment: `ispcname(c.Value) = True Or isip(c.Value) = True` functions only checks some conditions with the value and returns a Boolean, shouldn't be the reason (I will test it anyway). Tried `ActiveSheet.Parent.Save` same result as `ThisWorkbook.Save`. I also taught of separating it for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening at all, but one workaround seems to be calling `Workbook_BeforeSave` manually and then disabling it for the `ActiveWorkbook.Save` call:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbook_BeforeSave False, False    'Manual call.
    Me.Save                             'Save without the event firing again.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

That said, you also have some curious logic in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` handler. First, I don't think that `For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count` is doing what you think it's doing. It isn't necessarily going to loop over the entire column, because `UsedRange.Cells` doesn't have to start at row 1.  If your used range is something like `$A$4:$Z$100`, `rng.Rows.Count` will be 97 and all of your references to `Cells(i, y)` would be off by 3.

It also isn't clear if `ispcname(c.Value) = True Or isip(c.Value) = True` and `Right(c, 1) = "$"` are mutually exclusive.  If they are, `If Right(c, 1) = "$"` should actually be an `ElseIf`.

Couple other things:

1. Executing 5 different statements in a one line `If` statement is
   incredibly hard to read and that makes it error prone. Use actual
   `If...End If` blocks unless the action is something trivial like
   `Exit Sub`.
2. The second `If Right(c, 1) = "$" Then` is always true. 
   It can be removed completely.
3. After actually formatting your code in
   a readable way, it's clear that you are using properties of `c` all
   over the place inside the `For Each c In rng` loop.  I'd put it in a
   `With` block.
4. You only need to use `ActiveSheet` once.  After that,
   you can either get it from `rng.Parent` or (much better) get a
   reference to it.
5. Get in the habit of using `String` returning
   functions instead of `Variant` returning functions when you need a
   `String`.  I.e. `Right$` instead of `Right` - the latter performs an
   implicit cast.
6. Fully qualify all of your references to `Cells`.
7. Avoid implicitly using the default properties of objects, i.e. `Range.Value`.
8. Use `Long` for row counters, not `Integer` to avoid the possibility for overflows.
9. [Use `vbNullString` instead of the literal `""`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796912/4088852).
10. `Font.Size` is measured in points.  It should be a number, not a string.

It should look more like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet    'Tip 4
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.Cells

    For Each c In rng
        With c  'Tip 3
            If ispcname(.Value) Or isip(.Value) Then  'Tip 1
                sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=vbNullString    'Tips 4 and 9
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Value = StrConv(.Value, vbProperCase)  'Tip 7
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 10     'Tip 10
            End If  'Pretty sure this should be an ElseIf structure here.
            If Right$(.Value, 1) = "$" Then  'Tips 5 and 7.
                y = .Column
                x = .Row
                Dim i As Long   'Tip 8
                For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count     'This is most likely wrong.
                    'Tip 2 used to be here.
                    If LCase$(sh.Cells(i, y).Value) = "backup" Then     'Tips 1, 5, and 6
                        .Value = sh.Cells(x, y - 2).Value & "$"   'Tips 4, 6, and 7
                        sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=vbNullString    'Tips 4 and 9
                        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
                        .Font.Size = 10     'Tip 10
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Really nice answer. The workaround part works as a charm. I know this is not the best coding. I wrote this part  when I was still beginner to code VBA. That `For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count` is to find a cell thats value is "backup" if found, under it if it has any cell that ends in character "$", copy the cell left from it by 2, and add the "$". The cells in the left are PC names that are used to connect to them by remotely, and in the right are hyperlinks to their backup. There is a `SheetFollowHyperlink` function that detects if it is a pc name -> open remotely, if pcname+"$", open its backup

Comment: 1. You are right, I will implement it. 2. "$" could be any random character, I use it to separate it from the PC names in the `SheetFollowHyperlink` function. 3. In newly written parts of my code, I use the `with` block. You are right, I will rewrite this as well. 4. True. 5. I don't understand this one. 6. Nor this point. 7. Got it. 8. Also a good idea but these lists are meant to be short like 100 x 20 maximum. 9. Have to do some research about this. 10. Back in the days this is how I found it on the web. Also useful info. I'll start working on implementing your code. And give a feedback.

Comment: @Divin3 - Glad it worked. The point of the note about `rng.Rows.Count` is the possibility that your indexing will get messed up if you have empty rows at the top of the sheet.  If you need to test the entire column, it's much more robust. `c.Row` is the absolute row number relative to the sheet, but `i` is relative to the first of `UsedRange`.

Comment: @Divin3 - Added hyperlinks on some of the items you said you didn't understand.

Comment: `.Value = StrConv$(.Value, vbProperCase)` gives me a "Sub of function not defined" error if I use `$`. The rest is working perfectly.

Comment: @Divin3 - You're right.  Not sure why I was thinking that `StrConv` had a `Variant` overload. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "$" to say that the cell is a currency, don't test if the last character is "$". you have to check if the cell has a currency format.

Modify the line

```
if right(c,1)= "$"
```

to

```
fc = c.NumberFormat
    If InStr(1, c, "$") = 0 Then ...
```

your test will never find the "$" in c.

Comment: if there is a `Then` in the same line as the `If`, there is no need for `End if`

Comment: @Divin3 - If your tests are structured property, then why are you testing `If isbackup = True` immediately after `isbackup = True`? Also, the `If isbackup = True` isn't consistently indented, which leads me to believe that it isn't intended to be inside the `If LCase(Cells(i, y).Value) = "backup" Then` block.

Comment: @Comintern @D.O. You're right in the `isbackup` part. Removed it.

Comment: It is not currency, it is a special kind of value that needs to be different from the one from 2 columns left to it so I use the character `$` it could have been any other character, I just chose "$" by random. To be more specific I store PC names as hyperlinks in my list in a column that I can connect remotely if I click them, and 2 columns right are hyperlinks that point to their backup. The hyperlinks are generated after the PC names.

Comment: I think it is better to take another character. Because, when I have tested your code and take some examples with numbers and add "$" at the right, the cells with a number and "$" are modified to currency. So, checking what is the last character will give us the last number and not the "$" at the end. So if you have numbers change "$" to another character.