# Excel VBA - Target.EntireRow excluding two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet that utilizes columns A:AV. I have it set to automatically copy and paste the entire row when a cell in column D has the text "Closed". I couldn't cut the row due to formatting that the sheet has, so instead I'm using this to clear the row      `Target.EntireRow.Value = ""`.  My question is, is it possible to set the values of the entire row to "" while skipping over columns W and X? I have formulas in those columns that I don't want to be erased. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Word of advice, I would not use `Value = ""` that does not clear the cells just puts a blank string in it. Use `Value = vbNullString`

Comment: Also, you could use a loop to clear each cell and add in `If` statements to skip over W and X

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SnWhte - can you provide some sort of test to show the difference of a cell that has had its `Value` set to `""` versus one that has had its `Value` set to `vbNullString`.  (I'm struggling to find one - all the tests I have tried in both VBA and Excel think they are both `Empty`.)

Comment: You won't see a difference it is more so for optimization and efficiency. If you use "" more rows will be in "use" than if you use `vbNullString`. Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435320/is-there-any-difference-between-vbnullstring-and) and the link they provide in the answer [here](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html)

Comment: @YowE3K see comment above, didn't realize you weren't OP

Comment: @SnWhte - I can understand the efficiency issues (the compiler can point to a constant null string instead of creating a new instance of one), but using `""` or `vbNullString` seems to give exactly the same effect on `UsedRange` (and everything else as far as Excel is concerned).  I admit to being surprised when I saw the behaviour - I expected **both** methods would leave a null string in the cell, and was not expecting it to be the same as doing a `ClearContents` - but that appears to be exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear all cells in a row except for columns W and X:

```
With Target.Parent
    Union(.Range(.Cells(Target.Row, "A"), .Cells(Target.Row, "V")), _
          .Range(.Cells(Target.Row, "Y"), .Cells(Target.Row, .Columns.Count))).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.