# How to bypass test on blank/empty MailItem.To property?

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

How do I bypass standard Outlook check function when user doesn't fill the MailItem object's `.To` property?

If `MailItem.To` is blank I receive an error message.

My goal is to create a function to check when the `.To` property is blank to avoid VBA error and show a msg box, stop VBA script until object .To is correctly filled.

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objWho As String

objWho = objMail.To

If objMail.To xxxEpmty.something Then
    MsgBox ("Object To is blank")
Else
    objWho = objMail.To
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Use vbNullString if its blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435320/is-there-any-difference-between-vbnullstring-and)*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(0)

    Dim objWho As String
        objWho = ""

        If objWho = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Error objwho is blank"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    With objMail
        .To = objWho
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

*You should also use Resolve or ResolveAll methods to resolve the Recipient against the address book.*

*[Recipient.Resolve method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipient.Resolve)*

*[Recipients.ResolveAll method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.ResolveAll)*

Answer (score 1):

The To property is a string.

```
Sub forceTo()

    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim strWho As String

    ' first create mail
    Set objMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    If objMail.To = "" Then
        MsgBox ("To field is blank")
    Else
        strWho = objMail.To
        MsgBox ("To field contains this text: " & strWho)
    End If

End Sub
```