# Why doesn't a String of Nothing cause cause an exception? (BC42104)

Tags: vb.net

If I declare a string but do not assign a value, the `Equals` function throws an exception but it doesn't throw an exception if it is compared to a value.

The error list warns about the problem:

> Warning   BC42104 Variable `a` is used before it has been assigned a
>   value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

```
Dim a As String
Dim b as string = "bar"

a.Equals("foo") 'causes System.NullReferenceException

a = "foo" 'No exception although a is nothing

a = b 'No exception although a is nothing
```

I know the warning says it COULD cause an exception, but does anyone know why this is the happening?

Comment: [Nothing and Strings in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/nothing-and-strings)

Comment: The warning is pretty much unrelated. It can always be `Nothing`, even if initialized; for example, the warning will go away if you write `Dim a As String = Nothing`. Is your real question about the difference between the `=` operator and the `.Equals` method?

Comment: `a.Equals` is calling a *member function* on `a`. Obviously you cannot call a member function on an object that is "null"/Nothing. However, the equality operator is special-cased to handle null objects.

Comment: (Also, please confirm that you’re using `a = "foo"` and `a = b` in an expression and not as a statement – preferably with real code – because it’s also a valid assignment statement. Since you already got an answer that was confused about that.)

Comment: To elaborate on what @CodyGray is saying, also note that [`string.operator==(string, string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,705), like all overloaded operators, is `static` (`Shared`), at no point does the .NET framework try to do `a.Equals` when it handles the `=` operator; [`string.Equals(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,570), on the other hand is an instance method of `String` and will cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Yes, these were in If statements

Comment: @TnTinMn: This behaviour has nothing to do with the “Nothing and Strings in Visual Basic” article, since VB compatibility functions aren’t involved.

Comment: @Ry, the question is slightly ambiguous in that the OP is performing string comparison operations.  Comparison is confirmed by the OP in a comment to the accepted answer. VB string comparisons can be a mine-field for those that do not know the language.  The Nothing(null) equal String.Empty ("") is one, Another is the `Option Compare Text` directive that causes `"a" = "A"` to equate to True. What does have absolutely nothing to do with this question is the duplicate hammer placed by Cody Gray.  Maybe [Nothing = String.Empty (Why are these equal?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633166)

Comment: @TnTinMn: But the question was why the comparison didn’t throw an exception. I don’t see the OP mentioning its value.

Comment: @Ry, From the VB language specification, Section 11.14: _When doing a string comparison, a null value is equivalent to the string literal ""_. So `a = "foo"` (a is Nothing) is evaluated as `"" = "foo"`.  That is not the actual implementation as there is no substitution of "" for a null string; it is implemented by calling the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.CompareString(String, String, Boolean) Method`.  As passing `Nothing` to that method is valid, there will be no exception thrown.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Yeah, but it’s not an exception in C# either. It’s just `false`. The reason it’s *able* to not be an exception is because the operator isn’t an instance method.

Comment: @ry, No, its an implementation detail in which the implementation does not throw an exception with a null argument.  But I doubt you will be convinced by that argument.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Sure, it’s part of the implementation, but `"".Equals(Nothing)` doesn’t throw an exception either, because it’s part of *that* implementation. `Nothing.Equals("")` doesn’t even have to involve implementation; it can’t possibly work, because it’s not an extension method. I think that’s the most accurate answer to the question as posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Dim a As String` declares the type of variable a but doesn't assign anything to it. This is basically saying : "This variable was made to hold a String object, but it doesn't hold any right now". On the other hand, `Dim b As String = "bar"` declares the variable and its type, but also assigns a String object to it ("bar"). The reason `a.Equals("foo")` returns an exception is because you only declared it without assigning anything to it (so you are trying to access an object that isn't there). `a = "foo"` works because you are assigning a String object of value "foo" to the variable a. It's like saying : "This variable now holds a String object with value 'foo'".

Edit :

While your code points to the assignment of the variable a, I was made aware that you wanted to know why the = operator, as a comparison operator, works. This is because what I said earlier isn't entirely true when I said it didn't hold an object. It actually is of Nothing value (which sets it as a null reference) if no String object was assigned to it (String is a nullable object).

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about string comparison -- "it doesn't throw an exception if it is compared to a value".  The code presented leads one to assume it is about assignment.

Comment: @TnTinMn this is true. I was looking at the code given. If the `a = "foo"` expression is used in an If statement, I assume it works because a is treated as a Nothing object, which works with the = operator.

Comment: You might as well cover both contingencies in your answer before someone else does.  Also look at the link I posted as comment.

Comment: Yes this was in an If statement. Hence I was expecting an exception (like in C#) but reading TnTinMn link I see now that the VB runtime treats a string of nothing as an empty string, which now makes sense of this.

Comment: @Uggy: ”Like in C#” – ? `null == "foo"` works fine in C# too with no exception.