# Local String-variable initialization in Loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach, local-variables, .net-4.8

I'm facing a strange behavior with vb.net (framework 4.8,VS2019, `Option Explicit` and `Strict` `On`) and a string variable inside a `For Each` loop.

Why the `tmpVal` variable is not reinitialized on each loop, or may I've missed something?

Here is my code :

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Props() As String = {"one", "two", "three"}
    For Each cProp As String In Props
        Dim tmpVal As String
        If cProp = "two" Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpVal) Then
                tmpVal = cProp
            Else
                tmpVal = "Nope"
            End If
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("cProp " & cProp & " : " & tmpVal)
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

and the output I get :

```
cProp one :
cProp two : two
cProp three : two
```

I was expecting the third row to be "empty"

Thank you

Comment: You only assign `tempVal` once when `cProp = "two" And String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpVal)`. Otherwise it's never updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a variable inside a loop does not mean it will be initialized on each iteration.

It just limits the scope to the loop.

Means it will be initialized once to `Nothing` in your example.

You can change the initialization as follows to get the expected result:

```
Dim tmpVal As String = ""
```

Comment: Thank you  you're right.  the related info at Microsoft if it can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope

Comment: I believe the String, being a reference type, is initialized to Nothing.

Comment: @Mary You're right. I got confused because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633166/nothing-string-empty-why-are-these-equal